# Top bar will be hidden when pop-up appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

When there's a pop-up alert or when the keyboard shows up, the navigationBar will be hidden automatically.

What may I do to avoid this?

Comment: Can you explain more about this..

Comment: @Shunzhe Ma, the top bar do you means `navigationBar`?

Comment: @aircraft I have set a navigationController in the view. And, when there an UIAlertController triggered, the top Bar ,which contains the title and some buttons in navigationController, will be automatically hidden with an animation.

Comment: @ShunzheMa, animation up and out the screen?

Comment: @aircraft Exactly. Animated up and then out of the screen. Even if the UIAlaertController has been hidden( closed), the Navigation bar is still not there.

Comment: @Shunzhe Ma, show me the code, and if u are using some librady such as `IQKeyboardManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the properties of Navigation Controller, deselect the box named under "Hide bars when keyboard appears" and the issue will be solved.